# Is **Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software** necessory for setting up hosted network in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

Is **Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software** necessory for setting up hosted network in windows 7.? I'd like to uninstall it to free up some space if it does not have much use and is not related to hosted network settings. What use does a commonn user have with **Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software** ? Some one please help..

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need the Intel provided software, it's mostly just a different user interface to give access to the driver, which is the only thing you actually need for your WiFi card to work properly.

From [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `The driver for the wireless adapter must implement the wireless LAN device driver model defined by Microsoft for use on Windows 7. To receive the Windows 7 logo, a wireless driver must implement the wireless Hosted Network feature.` ..

So as long as you have the [correct driver](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/), you should be good.

Hope that can help.

Comment: seems like **Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software** has an effect on **microsoft virtual wifi miniport adapter**. It just disapperared after uninstalling Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software. Now i cant start hosted network. Think i should do a system restore.

Comment: @Johnson: did you completely uninstall everything? If so that might have removed the driver for it too, and the default MS driver is loaded (which has basic capabilities)..Try grabbing just the driver from the Intel site and updating the driver on your WiFi card (through system management) and see if that brings back the hosted network capability ..?

Comment: i tried system restore and everything is fine as earlier (including that the 'Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software' is still back in my programs list). Will i get just the 'microsoft virtual wifi miniport adapter' from the intel site. (ps: Im a newbie with these things)